# Visual Basic DataRepeater Controls Disappear

Tags: visual-studio, corrupt, datarepeater

When I make any attribute changes to any control on my form, all of the controls within all DataRepeaters disappear within Visual Studio and when running the app. The DataRepeaters are the blocks with the header "Region A B W" and the area starting with the label "# Section Seq".

Form before making a change:

[image]

Form after making a change:

[image]

I would very much appreciate suggestions on how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Tracy

Comment: Please repost your screenshots at native resolution - they're too small to make sense of right now.

Comment: Question: Is this a monolithic form with all of the control instances represented by designer-generated fields in the `.designer.cs` file? Or is it structured with User Controls to keep things logically separated?

Comment: I do not understand "structured with User Controls"